# Why hyphen is added before error name

Tags: c

Why do the functions that return standard error values have a hyphen(-) before the error macro name? For example, I am tracing the code of a bootloader and it is each of the function eg: `return -EINVAL`

Comment: Huh? Can you shown an example?

Comment: Well I am tracing the code of a bootloader and it is each of the function eg: `return -EINVAL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this talks about functions in the Linux kernel, which is where I've seen this pattern.

This happens in functions that need to return a negative `int` to signify failure and that want to use the macros, but the values of the macros are positive.

Therefore, code that wishes to signal failure due to e.g. `EINVAL` will do

```
return -EINVAL;
```

So the hyphen is simply a prefix negation operator, that turns the positive value coming from the macro into something negative.

I guess the surrounding code (the syscall mechanisms) can then detect this and copy the actual error to `errno` while returning just `-1` to the user's call, or something. I haven't verified this, but it would make sense as a simple way to isolate the handling/propagation of the error code from the generation of it.